# libGL.so: undefined reference to `glapi_tls_Current'?

Tags: nvidia, compiling, gcc, opengl

I am a newbie trying to build a C++ project on Ubuntu 18.04, which I used to be able to build without any issues before updating from Ubuntu 16.04.
My machine has an NVIDIA GPU running with NVIDIA driver 440.31.

Now, after my OS update, `make` gives me the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `_glapi_tls_Current'

How do I solve this problem?

**What I've tried:**
I've followed part of the answer on https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/undefined-reference-to-%60_glapi_tls_dispatch%27-how-can-i-solve-this-error-4175458263/

1. First, `readlink -f "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so"`
2. That gave me `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0` so I checked it using `ldd`
3. `libglapi.so.*` was not listed in the result, but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:
`-D WITH_OPENGL=OFF`

The error might be caused while building with OPENGL. so, if you don't need opengl support, please turn it off to see if the error goes away.

Comment: Care to explain what this does in the answer?